# How to Apply Discount Based on Shipping Method in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to give my customers a 20 percent discount when they choose the "pick up in store" shipping method in Woocommerce. I used the code below but I got an error. How can I apply it only in the "delivery from store" option?

Wordpres: 6.4.2
Woocommerce: 8.4.0

```
    // Sepet tablosuna bir sütun ekleyerek "mağzadan teslim" seçeneğini kontrol et
function add_delivery_option_to_cart() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('body').on('change', 'input[name="shipping_method[0]"]', function () {
                var is_store_pickup = $(this).val() === 'local_pickup:1'; // "local_pickup:1" mağzadan teslim seçeneğinin değeridir
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                    data: {
                        'action': 'is_store_pickup',
                        'is_store_pickup': is_store_pickup,
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_delivery_option_to_cart');

// Mağzadan teslim seçildiyse sepet toplamına indirim uygula
function apply_discount_for_store_pickup() {
    if (is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                $(document.body).on('updated_checkout', function () {
                    var is_store_pickup = $('input[name="shipping_method[0]"]:checked').val() === 'local_pickup:1';
                    if (is_store_pickup) {
                        var discount_percentage = 20; // İndirim yüzdesi
                        var cart_total = parseFloat($('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
                        var discount_amount = (cart_total * discount_percentage) / 100;
                        var discounted_total = cart_total - discount_amount;
                        $('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').html('<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">' + $('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').find('.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol').html() + '</span>' + discounted_total.toFixed(2));
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'apply_discount_for_store_pickup');

// AJAX işlemleri için fonksiyon
function is_store_pickup() {
    if (isset($_POST['is_store_pickup'])) {
        WC()->session->set('is_store_pickup', $_POST['is_store_pickup']);
        echo 'success';
    }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_is_store_pickup', 'is_store_pickup');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_is_store_pickup', 'is_store_pickup');
```

Comment: In your question there are 0 (zero) really neccessary details where we would be able to help you, like specific information of WooCommerce version, relevant part of code, nothing... If you don't want to provide details, then you might as well go on Google, search "WooCommerce discount apply based on shipping method php" and paste random scripts and see which one's working.

Comment: To help you update the question, we need following information:
Details of shipping methods - like ID or names of shipping methods, are there any specific customizations or plugins you are using that might be affecting the cart or checkout process, version of woocommerce and wordpress, details how you want to apply discount, should it be before or after tax calcs, your website's theme....

Answer (score 0):

This True Answer

```
// Mağzadan teslim seçildiyse sepet toplamına indirim uygula
function apply_discount_for_store_pickup( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // Hedeflenen "Mağzadan Teslim" seçeneği
    $target_shipping_method = 'local_pickup:1';

    // Varsa sepetin içeriğini kontrol et
    if ( WC()->session->__isset( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) ) {
        // Seçilen gönderim yöntemlerini al
        $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

        // "Mağzadan Teslim" seçeneği sepete eklendiyse
        if ( in_array( $target_shipping_method, $chosen_methods ) ) {
            $discount_percentage = 18; // İndirim yüzdesi

            // İndirim miktarını hesapla
            $discount_amount = $cart->subtotal * $discount_percentage / 100;

            // İndirimi sepete uygula
            $cart->add_fee( 'Mağzadan Teslim Alacağınız İçin İndirim', -$discount_amount );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'apply_discount_for_store_pickup', 10, 1 );
```